# matlab surface plot with multiple data sets

Tags: matlab, plot, surface

I am working with voltage data taken from LiPo batteries at various temperatures and charge levels. I took voltage measurements at 10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, and 90% charge levels as i varied the cell temperature.

my question is how to best turn this into a surface plot, using temperature as the X axis, charge level as the Y axis, and cell voltage as the Z axis.

my data is currently stored as a separate voltage and temperature array, at each charge level. i have only used matlab a few times before so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at [Representing data as a surface](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/representing-a-matrix-as-a-surface.html) - there's quite a few examples that should cover your case as well. Use `meshgrid` to generate the grid over which you plot, and for example `surf` for plotting the surface.